# Connect multiple Databases to .NET core project via Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a .NET core application that connects to multiple databases, but using one generic repository that contains the logic for all CRUD operations. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
    public Repository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _set = _dbContext.Set<T>();
    }
```

Above is the constructor of my repository. Here, I inject the ApplicationDbContext. I am looking for a way to make this ApplicationDbContext generic, so I only have to need only one repository, in which I can inject different contexts for accessing multiple databases. Essentially I am looking for something like this:

```
public class Repository_1<T> where T:EntityBase
{
    public Repository_1(IDbContext dbContext)
    {

    }
}
```

Where I can swap out the dbContext and replace it with another context that connects to another Database.

Comment: So in your scenario you have different databases with identical schemas? Or is each schema unique?

Comment: No, each schema is unique.

Comment: So you essentially want a repo container to hold all your contexts?

Comment: You mean something like this: https://ibb.co/2t9sPqH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set two parameters for your repository and add constrains on them, asusume that your dbContext is inherited from `DbContext`

```
public class TestRepository<TContext, T> : ITestRepository<TContext,T> 
    where TContext : DbContext
    where T : BaseEntity
{

    private readonly TContext _context;
    private DbSet<T> entities;


    public TestRepository(TContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        entities = context.Set<T>();
    }



    public List<T> GetAll()
    {

        return entities.AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }
}
```

ITestReposiroty:

```
public interface ITestRepository<TContext,T>
    where TContext : DbContext
    where T : BaseEntity
{       
    List<T> GetAll();
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(ITestRepository<,>), typeof(TestRepository<,>));
```

Controller:

```
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ITestRepository<ApplicationDbContext, Product> _repository;

    public TestRepoController(ITestRepository<ApplicationDbContext, Product> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    // GET api/products

    [HttpGet]
    public List<Product> Get()
    {
        return _repository.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Create base context and including all settings into this, DBSET:

```
public abstract class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    public BaseContext(DbContext options)
    : base(options)
    { }
    public DbSet<object> FirstDbSet { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

inherit from BaseContext for both DBs(Databases):

```
public class NavaContext : BaseContext
{
    public NavaContext (DbContext<NavaContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}

public class StackContext : BaseContext
{
    public StackContext(DbContext<StackContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

and register both in `Startup.cs`:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<NavaContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LATAMConnectionString")));
    services.AddDbContext<StackContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("EUConnectionString")));

    // Autofac
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // needed only if you plan to inject ICollection<BaseContext>
    builder.RegisterType<NavaContext>().As<BaseContext>();
    builder.RegisterType<StackContext>().As<BaseContext>();

    builder.Populate(services);


    return new AutofacServiceProvider(builder.Build());
}
```

add connection strings in `appsettings.json`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "NavaConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ContosoUniversity1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
  "StackConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ContosoUniversity1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

and now you can inject both contexts:

```
public class ReportRepository : IReportRepository
{
    private readonly NavaContext latamDbContext;
    private readonly StackContext euDbContext;

    public ReportRepository(NavaContext latamDbContext, StackContext euDbContext)
    {
        this.latamDbContext = latamDbContext;
        this.euDbContext = euDbContext;
    }
}
```

or if you plan to inject `collection` of contexts:

```
public class ReportRepository : IReportRepository
{
    private readonly ICollection<BaseContext> dbContexts;

    public ReportRepository(ICollection<BaseContext> dbContexts)
    {
        this.dbContexts = dbContexts;
    }
}
```

to access specific context:

```
var _stackContext= dbContexts.FirstOrDefault(x => x is StackContext) as StackContext;
var _navaContext= dbContexts.FirstOrDefault(x => x is NavaContext) as NavaContext;
```

Comment: Could I help you?

Comment: Almost - I actually want to have one repository per type, e.g. a user repository, that I need to connect to the right database (the one with the table User in it). I don't want a collection of contexts in my repository, only one. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes of course.
Choose an optimal repository method and you can define two databases.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

In your RepositoryBase class:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TContext, TEntity>
   where TContext : DbContext
   where Entity: class 

public TContext Context { get; private set; }

public RepositoryBase(TContext context)
{
    this.Context = context;
}

public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
        return this.Context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();
}
```

Usage from a specific repository:

```
public class ComputerGroupRepo : RepositoryBase<RequestContext, ComputerGroup> 
{
    public ComputerGroupRepo()
       : base(new RequestContext())
    {
    }

    public IQueryable<ComputerGroup> GetComputerGroups()
    {
        IQueryable<ComputerGroup> result = this.GetAll()
            .Include(v => v.ComputerGroupIps);

        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

BaseRepository class can use like this and it is use inheritance on data access layer classes.

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TContext> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : class 
    where TContext : DbContext, new()
    {
        private readonly DbContext _context;
        private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;
        public GenericRepository()
        {
            _context = new TContext();
            _dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
        }
    
    }
```

Data access class;

```
public class ProductDal:GenericRepository<Product,AppDbContext>,IProductDal
{
}
```

If use dependency injection data access classes must be registered. Generic Repository can not register, because it instance inside class. _context = new TContext();